# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in TasksController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've started learning Ruby on Rails today, but i'm getting this error:

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in TasksController#create

The error message says the error is on 'Task.create params[:task]'

```
def create
    Task.create params[:task]
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController


def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def create
    Task.create params[:task]
    redirect_to :back
  end

end
```

Index:

```
    <h1>Task</h1>
<%= form_for Task.new do|f| %>
   <%= f.label :task %>
   <%= f.text_field :task %>
   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
<ul>
    <% for task in @tasks %>
    <li><%= task.task %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: welome to SO, next time, try searching your error first https://www.google.com.co/search?q=ActiveModel%3A%3AForbiddenAttributesError

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue also.  Replace the following line:
params.require(:task).permit(:task)

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def create
    Task.create task_params
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:task)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that is solved by strong params.  I won't give you a lesson on strong params, it's been talked about to death but basically you need to tell your controller that certain params are allowed.  The [rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) explains it wonderfully:

> 4.5 Strong Parameters With strong parameters, Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments
>   until they have been whitelisted. This means you'll have to make a
>   conscious choice about which attributes to allow for mass updating and
>   thus prevent accidentally exposing that which shouldn't be exposed.

That said, I don't know all of your `Task` attributes but it would look something like this:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController


def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def create
    Task.create task_params
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name, :title, :body, :otherstuff)
  end

end
```